# How long do you have to make an ajax response?

Tags: ajax

On my site, I want to make some ajax requests to the server. The server is going to have to do some pretty heavy computations before it can return a response; I'm thinking it may take 1-30 seconds, maybe as much as a minute. Would this cause any problems? Such as, would your browser close the connection? If so, should I look at other technologies, such as push notifications with node.js+socket.io?

Answer (score 2):

In most cases the browser won't close the connection in the timeframe you mention (1-30 sec) BUT it might look "funny" to the user.
That aside I would ALWAYS make such heavy lifting ASYNC... that open up the possibility to scale... depending on what happens network-wise push notification might not always wotrk but are a good idea... perhaps you can combine that with very moderate polling (i.e. every 15 sec or so).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know off the top of my head, but 30 seconds sounds way too long. And if it can take 30 seconds today, it will probably take 5 minutes six moths after you launch your product or service.

Why not create a polling system. Make your initial request call to kick off the background computation, then make polling ajax calls every second to see if it has finished. When you finally get success, make a call to the method which returns finished results.

Comment: It won't take 5 minutes down the road, I'm specifically limiting it to a certain time-frame. I was trying to avoid repeatedly polling the server...every user on the site is going to be initiating these requests; I want to keep it as light as possible.

Comment: If a lot of users will be simultaneously hitting your server, then you REALLY need to consider a polling solution. You can run out of sockets quickly with a lot of users. And if you have a lot of servers, your load balancers HATE keeping connections alive.

Comment: So you're saying it's better to use ajax and poll than to use sockets and keep many connections alive? By "many"... I don't anticipate my site becoming overly popular. Maybe 100-1000 users online at a time if I'm lucky!

Answer (score 1):

There is no standardized timeout for AJAX requests. Contrary to what @Yahia is saying, most browsers will **eventually** close a lingering connection. I checked this on several browsers a couple of years ago. Firefox, for example, would close the connection several hours in. What you're trying to do should be solved by using websockets or (long-)polling with a set timeout that refreshes the request.

No modern browser should close the connection in 30 seconds or a minute, but you never know.